# Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException - Invalid object name 'GuestList'.'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sqlexception

I'm having a big issue with my Database, I cannot write to it from the web page. I am using Dapper as my ORM if that makes a difference?

db.Insert(guest.EditableGuest); is giving me the invalid object error [image] but if I change it to db.InsertAsync(guest.EditableGuest); the error resolves itself BUT I cannot get it to add to the DB and it will not be displayed on the page where I have a list of guests in the DB for some reason?

I decided to retype the page again in case there was an issue, VS seems to be a bit finicky sometimes, one day I had an error, closed the app, reopened it and it was fine? Didn't work with this unfortunately.

GuestListController

```
using Dapper.Contrib.Extensions;
    using FYP_RSVP_MGMT.Helpers;
    using FYP_RSVP_MGMT.Models;
    using FYP_RSVP_MGMT.ViewModels;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using System.Linq;

    namespace FYP_RSVP_MGMT.Controllers
    {
        public class GuestListController : Controller
        {
            public IActionResult Index()
            {
                GuestListViewModel guest = new GuestListViewModel();

               return View("Index", guest);
    }

    /* Create or Update a guest RSVP Response */

    public IActionResult CreateUpdate(GuestListViewModel guest)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var db = DbHelpers.GetConnection())
            {
                /* If a guestID is null, the number of existing guests will be counted
                 * in order to determine what the next guestID will be and will be added 
                 * asynchronously to the DB in case other actions are on going at the same time */
                 
                if (guest.EditableGuest.GuestID == null)
                {
                    guest.EditableGuest.GuestID = guest.Guests.Count;

                    db.Insert<GuestList>(guest.EditableGuest);
                }

                /* If the guest already exists, we are updating their details */
                else
                {
                    GuestList dbItem = db.Get<GuestList>(guest.EditableGuest.GuestID);

                    TryUpdateModelAsync<GuestList>(dbItem, "EditableGuest");

                    db.Update<GuestList>(dbItem);
                }
            }

            /* When a guest submits their RSVP response, it will bring them to the View Guests page - TEMPORARY MEASURE */
            return RedirectToAction("ViewGuestList", guest);
        }

        else
        {
            return View("ViewGuestList", new GuestList());
        }
    }
```

There is more code for Edit and Delete beyond this and the page is throwing no errors so that's all fine.

This is my DB Helper class

```
public class DbHelpers
{
    public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=WeddingDB;");
    }
}
```

GuestList Model

```
public class GuestList
{
    [ExplicitKey]
    public int? GuestID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string GuestName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string GuestType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ContactDetails { get; set; }

    public bool PlusOne { get; set; }

    public string PlusOneName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string GuestResponse { get; set; }
}
```

GuestListViewModel

```
 public class GuestListViewModel
{
    /* Creating a new List of all Guests 
     Editable Guest will hold any instance of an object from the list
            that is being added/edited/deleted etc */
    public List<GuestList> Guests { get; set; }

   
    public GuestList EditableGuest { get; set; }


    /* Selecting all of the existing guests from the DB */
    public GuestListViewModel()
    {
        using (var db = DbHelpers.GetConnection())
        {
            this.EditableGuest = new GuestList();

            this.Guests = db.Query<GuestList>("Select * From GuestList").ToList();
        }
    }

 
}
```

GuestList View

```
@model FYP_RSVP_MGMT.ViewModels.GuestListViewModel

    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Guest RSVP";
     }

    @* Form to submit RSVP Response *@

    @using (var form = Html.BeginForm("CreateUpdate", "GuestList", FormMethod.Post))
    {
<div class="container" id="GuestRSVP">

    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

    @* The Bride and Groom name plus Wedding Details will eventually change 
        depending on the log in details *@

    <h3> Welcome to [Bride] and [Groom]'s Wedding</h3>
    <h4>[Church Location]</h4>
    <h4>[Wedding Date and Time]</h4>

    <div class="container" id="RSVPTable" style="align-content:center">

        <table>

            <tr>
                <td>Guest Name: </td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EditableGuest.GuestName)</td>

            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Guest Type: </td>
                <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EditableGuest.GuestType, new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Value = "Guest", Text = "Guest" }, new SelectListItem { Value = "Wedding Party", Text = "Wedding Party" } })</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Email Address: </td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EditableGuest.ContactDetails)</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Plus One: </td>
                <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.EditableGuest.PlusOne)</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Plus One Name: </td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EditableGuest.PlusOneName)</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>RSVP Response:</td>
                <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EditableGuest.GuestResponse, new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Value = "Accept", Text = "Accept with Pleasure" }, new SelectListItem { Value = "Decline", Text = "Decline with Regret" } })</td>
            </tr>

        </table>

        <br/>

        <button class="btnSubmitRSVP" type="submit" style="text-align:center"> <a asp-controller="GuestList" asp-action="CreateUpdate"></a> @(Model.EditableGuest.GuestID > 0? "Update": "Submit Response") </button>


    </div>


</div>
```

}

Where I am sending some of the pages is probably a bit odd, like a guest RSVPing shouldn't be taken to the page where they can see the other guests and their response but this is just temporary. Could this be affected my code, surely not? Nowhere in my code is there GuestLists so I cannot understand where it is picking this up? I can provide more code if required.

Thank you for your help in advance!

***Edit: Here is a picture of the database***
[image]

Comment: Do you have this table in database?

Comment: @vivek nuna Yes, I've just edited the original post and included a picture of the database

Comment: I think you should set the guestId to count + 1 not equal to count for new record.

Comment: That didn't make any difference unfortunately, still can't insert a record

Comment: maually increasing the count will get you intotrouble, when comes ti multiple users and heavy duty on the server

Answer (score 4):

Dapper is assuming a pluralized table name. Use `[Table("GuestList")]` attribute in your `GuestList` model class.

Comment: AH that worked! Thank you so much! I didn't know that, I'll have to remember that going forward